# Building VirtualBox Guest Additions on a Ubuntu 20.04 VM fails

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am trying to build VirtualBox Guest additions since a few hours an a Ubuntu20.04 VM, but it keeps on failing. Installing it via Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image fails. /var/log contains

```
[...] ERROR: kernel configuration is invalid [...] run make oldconfig && make prepare on kernel src to fix it.
```

[image]

It looks quite similar to what is found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287205/building-the-main-guest-additions-module-fail). Running

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11
```

also fails, though in the log file I can only find warnings and no real errors.

The answers provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287205/building-the-main-guest-additions-module-fail) did not work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try downloading the iso from [https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/).

Comment: Didn't work. It's also the same iso file as was downloaded by the GUI. I attached a screenshot to show my errror output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualbox 6.1.10 does not support kernel 5.8.  If you look at [Virtualbox's CHANGELOG](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.1), you can find which version of Virtualbox will work.  I always recommend upgrading to the latest but it looks like 6.1.14 is when Oracle added kernel 5.8 support.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to install it now. However, mounting the shared folder via sudo mount -t vboxsf shared_folder /home/user/shared_folder ... now leads to /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory. I tried cd /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-**/init && sudo ./vboxadd setup, but I am still unable to mount the shared folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the kernel module loaded? If you do `lsmod | grep vboxsf` does anything show up?

Comment: No, nothing shows up.

Comment: Solved it, works now. Thanks.